# mongoose -- how to start session for transactions from the connection object? always throwing "no transaction started"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I have a nestjs project using mongoose under the hoood to interact with a mongo db.

The issue I'm having is I can't seem to start a session successfully from the connection object itself. Whenever I try to use the resulting session it will throw either:

```
MongoError: No transaction started
```

100% of the time for

```
  public async get_session(): Promise<ClientSession> {
    const session = await this.connection.startSession();

    return session;
  }
```

And intermitently, it will throw:

```
MongoError: Given transaction number 2 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 1
```

variants for the following implementation:

```
public get_session(): ClientSession {
    return this.connection.getClient().startSession();
  }
```

Looking at the docs -- either should work but in practice this does not seem to be the case.

Versions used:

```
    "mongoose": "^5.11.18",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
    "typescript": "4.0.6",
```